# Probability that d-Brownian Motion ,$d\geq 3$, avoids a fixed set A

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In other words, the probability that Brownian motion stays within $A^{c}$.

What about for connected and fixed compact sets ? Would that involve solving a heat equation? How can I condition it, so that it's solutions will avoid a set?

I am asking about the "specific" probability of not hitting non-polar sets (positive hitting probability). For example for d-sphere we know the hitting probability to be $(\frac{r}{x})^{d-2}$. So avoiding it is $1-(\frac{r}{x})^{d-2}$.

What would be the probability of avoiding two spheres?

Feel free to reference any book or paper.

Thanks

Comment: How can the probability of avoiding an open set (or set with interior) be one? Suppose an open set $A$ is almost surely avoided. We can take rotated copies of it to to cover a spherical layer $L=B(0,R)\setminus B(0,r)$ for some $0<r<R$. Since the BM is rotationally invariant, it almost surely avoids $L$. By continuity, the BM stays almost surely in a bounded set. This is false. (Or did I miss something?)

Comment: This problem was completely solved by Kakutani in the 50s, at least when $A^c$ is closed. In this case, a Brownian motion started in $A$ has zero probability of hitting $A^c$ if and only if $A^c$ has zero capacity for the potential $|x|^{2-d}$. In fact much more is known, see Chapter 8.3 of the Brownian motion book of Mörters and Peres.

Comment: @PabloShmerkin Thanks. But I was asking about the specific probability. For example for d-sphere we know it to be $1-(\frac{r}{x})^{d-2}$.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta here is a paper on the cylinders http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/burdzy.pdf

Comment: @PabloShmerkin Specific not-hitting probability of non-polar sets

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: The statement is, with probability 1, there *exists* a cylinder which is not hit.  The cylinder depends on the outcome $\omega$, hence the phrase "random cylinder".  This is actually quite a different question than computing the probability of avoiding a *fixed* set, so I think perhaps the question should be clarified.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah, I see. That way it makes perfect sense. To me it seems that the question asks about fixed sets; I thought the random set was fixed fixed before starting the BM.